# use gallery image for multi-models in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi In may project I have tow models Post and Products And they have galleryimage my question is how can use one table for gallery to handle it?

or better way is using tow separate gallery table for each model like PostGallery and ProductGallery?

relation between gallery and post or product is one to many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some solutions, first you can make separate gallery for each model, second you can make a model for storing gallery and use morph relation on it for handling which model belongs item to it, third one is using [spatie medialibrary package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary)

Comment: Not really, it just depends on what is suitable for your to pick as a solution. If you want to separate each gallery then you have to implement it yourself, if you decide to use morph then it worth to take a look to spatie package and then decide if it has whole your needs or not.